# I have package hyper ref warning

Tags: hyperref

I have around 25 warning about package hyperref warning: token not allowed in a pdf string removing math shift
At each \subsubsection in paper.
How to solve it?
Can expert help me?

Comment: Show a complete minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Special symbols (including many math symbols) are not allowed in the bookmarks. Provide an alternative string

```
 \subsection{text \texorpdfstring{$\alpha$}{alpha} text}
```